# Partial Update a document in OpenSearch using java HighLevelRestClient

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-opensearch

I have the following model. This also corresponds to the JSON document I have stored in OpenSearch.

```
public class Employee {

    private PersonalDetails personalDetails;

    private EducationalDetails educationalDetails;

    private WorkExperience workExperience;

    // getters, setters
}
```

I am trying to update the document corresponding to 'employee' partially in OpenSearch using java HighLevelRestClient. The intention is to update only workExperience or personalDetails or educationalDetails depending on what the user is trying to update.

This is the code that I tried (for updating personalDetails):

```
UpdateRequest<Employee, PersonalDetails> updateRequest =
                new UpdateRequest.Builder<Employee, PersonalDetails> ()
                        .index(index)
                        .id(id)
                        .doc(document)
                        .source(sourceConfig)
                        .refresh(Refresh.True)
                        .build();
openSearchClient.update(updateRequest, Employee.class);
```

This gives me serialization exceptions. Please help point out what I am doing wrong or please suggest another way of doing this.